# Simple SQL Problem

Tags: sql, database, aggregate-functions

Hey...I am in a bind here. I am not much of a programmer but the guy who does the sql at my business is out sick.

If I have a table like this (I am simplifying this a lot but this is where I am stuck).

```
Name Object   Payment

Joe  A         100
Jan  A         200
Joe  A         300
Ron  A         500
Jan  A         100
Joe  B         200
```

How do I write a query that would give me:

```
Joe A    300
Jan A    200
Ron A    500
Joe B    200
```

Essentially the highest value in the Payment field for each name. Thanks.  Sorry if I sound dumb...but I just cant find anything on the internet to help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select Name, Object, max(Payment)
from table
group by Name, Object
```

Answer (score 10):

```
select Name, Object, max(Payment) as MaxPayment
from MyTable
group by Name, Object
```

Comment: Sorry...i made a change to my question.  Good answer though. Sorry...im such a noob.

Comment: @user466334: I revised my answer accordingly.

Comment: Fastest gun ... SO is unfair and that is great news.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
SELECT Name, Object, MAX(Payment)
FROM   MyTable
GROUP BY Name, Object
```